# Can a Nano Server host a GUI Windows app (say Word) container running on top it?

Tags: windows-server-2012, docker, docker-for-windows

I understand that Nano server does not contain any GUI related component, and it can host windows containers running on top of it.

Most of the talks and examples I can found so far are the ones that application containers running on top of the Nano Server does not need any GUI functionality (e.g., IIS server) -- i.e., normally those application containers run Docker images are built from Nano Server images `FROM microsoft/nanoserver`

My question is whether a Nano server host may be able to host a GUI application such as Word within a container running on top of it. (Theoretically it feels feasible because as long as the Docker image of the container include the GUI package, but I am not sure)

- If it's possible, should I build the Docker image from Server Core image `FROM microsoft/windowsservercore` or should I build from the full Desktop experience server?

Comment: This is not possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106696/docker-container-for-windows-desktop-app

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to do that. Even setup procedures have to be changed:

"Because Nano Server is a headless OS, any GUI-based application has to be refactored to follow the client-server model that allows for remote installation, and for the GUI to be run on the client."

More at the [MS blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nanoserver/2015/11/18/installing-windows-server-apps-on-nano-server/)

Comment: You should include the relevant information from your link.

Comment: I think I did, by posting the quote - if you think it can be improved, please suggest edits

Comment: If I am going to collect the required information from your link, it would be easier, to submit my own answer

Comment: do you know if this is true for windowsservercore also? I'm trying to get something installed in a container that only has a GUI installer.

Comment: no, this is not true for server core. you are limited but there is a server side gui